# Fail to install Git with MacPorts

Tags: macos, git

I am trying to install Git and OpenJDK 6 using MacPorts, however when I type:

```
$ sudo port install git-core
```

it returns:

> sudo: port: command not found

I think it might be a path problem, but I am new to Mac so I don't how to fix it. Can someone help?

Comment: This is not a development question, so you should post it on Ask Different (Mac-specific site): http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use this to install git under OS X.

http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/

At your current level of experience with OS X I would also recommend that you stick with the Oracle Java 7 distribution which works quite well for Mountain Lion and Apple Java 6 for Lion and earlier (if you need the JDK-bits they can be downloaded from ADC).